# ReactJS - Array Callback Return

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this case, I'm making a sum of the object and its working just as I wanted to, the problem is the following message:

> Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return

Here is the code:

```
data.map((current,index, array) => {
    const prevVisitors = array[index - 1 ] ? array[index - 1].visitors : 0
    current.visitors += prevVisitors
})
```

What should I use as a return statement if there is nothing to be returned(Since it's only a modification of the props)? And in what cases this error is useful?

Comment: `map` works that you need to return the changed value so you can `return current` after you changed it, even if in these cases a `forEach` could be more suitable

Comment: I didn't thought that way, it's really a misuse of the map function, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
data.map((current,index, array) => {
    const prevVisitors = array[index - 1 ] ? array[index - 1].visitors : 0
    return current.visitors += prevVisitors
})
```

Comment: Yes, I used this at first, but with the answer of @quirimmo I thought better, and use forEach it's a better practice than return the current value, thanks